# Support for “border-radius” in Firefox 24

Tags: css, firefox

in Mozilla Firefox 24 i cannot use -moz-border-radius on my CSS style.
i have read from [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/13) article, they said

> Support for -moz-border-radius* and -moz-box-shadow has been removed. Authors should use unprefixed border-radius or box-shadow instead

but it is for Firefox 13, how about in version 24? anyway, thanks.

Comment: simple border-radius should also work check http://jsfiddle.net/E7kYt/ in your FF

Comment: Do you really expect every change like this to be repeated for every subsequent version's release notes even after the change was made in some earlier version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `border-radius: 5px 30px;`and `box-shadow: 0 1px 4px #222;` from now on

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you can stack both properties, as long as you put the -moz version first. If a particular version of Firefox doesn't like border-radius, it will fall back to the -moz version. And if a version doesn't like the -moz property, it will be superceded by the second call. (this works with -webkit-border-radius as well)

```
-moz-border-radius: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius#Browser_compatibility

```
#box{
    border:10px solid #000;
    border-radius: 10px 40px 40px 10px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color:#ccc;
}
```

check http://jsfiddle.net/E7kYt/ in your FF

Answer (score 0):

standard border radius for all browsers can be created in [border-radius.com](http://border-radius.com/)